# placing value in API URL and Call it back to save the data

Tags: java, android, api

How can i make

(URL)+loc=&message=&datetimefinal=&idno=

to

(URL)+loc=1&message=message&datetimefinal=finaldatetime&idno=1

msg(message)value is global variable, and i get finaldatetime by using Date().

this is the code that im working with

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    String datefinal = dateFormat.format(date).toString();
    final String BASEPATH = "URL";

   Retrofit retrofit  = new Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(BASEPATH)
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
           .build();
    DeviceData deviceData = retrofit.create(DeviceData.class);

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("location", "1");
    params.put("datetime", datefinal);
    params.put("msg", message);
    params.put("id", "1");

    deviceData.getMyThing(params, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"test2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
        // ... do some stuff here.
    );
}
```

and this is my Interface

```
public interface DeviceData {

@GET("/mobile_alerts_api.php?")
void getMyThing(Map<String, String>map,Callback<String> callback);
```

now, iI'm having error said that " Must have either a return type or Callback as last argument.". im using retrofit2. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make these changes :

```
 @GET("/mobile_alerts_api.php?")
    void getMyThing(Map<String, String>map,Callback<String> callback);
```

Change this to

```
 @GET("/mobile_alerts_api.php?")
    Call<String> getMyThing(@FieldMap Map<String, String> map,Callback<String> callback);
```

It will work , if your logics are correct.

Hope it Helps !!.

Comment: this is the error that occurs 

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
for method DeviceData.getMyThing

Comment: @MNGorospe Updated answer, added annotations ...kindly check now !!